# IIS server not getting file having spaces in name

Tags: php, linux, laravel, windows, iis

I have moved a laravel 5.8 application on a windows server. Previously it was a linux server. I want to access the pdf file present in the folder directory.

The example of the URL is given below.
`http://somedomain/my_app/pdf-documents/Casablanca%20Airport%20-%20CMN%7C264.pdf`

When accessing the above url on linux server it gives the correct file but when accessing the same file on IIS server it gives 404.

The actual file name is **Casablanca Airport - CMN | 264.pdf**.

Both have same url structure adding %20 or respective character's in the places. But file is not opening on *IIS* gives 404 but gives file on *LINUX* server.

Comment: Check your IIS logs, you should get a sub-status code such as 404.5 or something. You might need to adjust [request filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/use-request-filtering)

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the URL encoded string. On Windows OS, It is not allowed to use “|” character in the file name. therefore, please check the actual file name in your IIS web server. On my side, the character “|” is automatically omitted in the name of the file.
[image]
In the Chrome browser, we could directly type the full name of the PDF file, the Chrome will help us automatically convert to the correct URL encoded string.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.